# Localize script not working

Tags: ajax, localization

I am testing ajax in wordpress, and it basically works but I do not want the url to be hardcoded, so I tried using `wp_localize_script` to get an object to use, but I get an error saying: "ReferenceError: WPURLS is not defined" when alerting the siteurl in `ajax_script.js`.

functions.php

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'ajax_script',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax_script.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );

wp_localize_script('ajax_script', 'WPURLS', array( 'siteurl' => get_option('siteurl') ));
```

ajax_script.js

```
$(function () {

    $('#vru-btn').click(function() {
        // alert('code');
        $.post( 'wp-content/themes/wpcleantheme/ajax/test.php', function(data) {
            $('#vru-div').html(data);    
        });
    });;

    alert(WPURLS.siteurl);
});
```

Comment: You are adding `siteurl` but trying to access `template_url`. :)

Comment: I was testing two methods so it got mixed up, but that's not the problem. I changed it (as it was before), but the issue is it not recognizing WPURLS object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `wp_localize_script` before the action that enqueues the script has run. Move the localize into the enqueue action, after the script is enqueued.

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'ajax_script',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax_script.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
    wp_localize_script('ajax_script', 'WPURLS', array( 'siteurl' => get_option('siteurl') ));
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

That said, you probably don't want to be directing requests directly to template files, as you won't have access to any of the WordPress API that way. Instead, direct requests to `admin_url('admin-ajax.php')`, and read up on using [AJAX in Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Comment: Thanks. I will more likely be using it in plugins, this is just for testing. I included 'wp-load.php' in my theme file so as to have access to the WP API, do you think this is a bad idea?

Comment: depends on the context. it's probably ok for your own purposes, but bad if you will distribute this code. wp-load.php isn't necessarily in the same place on all installs, so it's prone to failure. WordPress.org plugin repository will reject any plugin that does that.

Answer (score 0):

Register the script, then localize it, then enqueue it. According to [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)

```
 // Register the script
 wp_register_script( 'some_handle', 'path/to/myscript.js' );

 // Localize the script with new data
 $translation_array = array(
'some_string' => __( 'Some string to translate', 'plugin-domain' ),
'a_value' => '10'
 );
 wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $translation_array );

 // Enqueued script with localized data.
 wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );
```

Comment: this way you can add dependent scripts and only run the enqueue once, but both solutions will work.